# Combine Two Json Objects in java which is in single json array

Tags: java, json

I have one Json array which is consist 2 or 3 json objects, now I need to combine both the json objects into single json object, 1st json object is coming from one method 2nd is coming from another method let me explain with example

```
response[
{
"id" : 1,
"name" : "Hi",
"no.of slots" [
  {
"Mrng" : 10:30,
"Evening" : 11:20
},
{
"Mrng" : 12:00,
"Evening" : 4:00
}
]
},

{
"email" : "abc@gmail.com",
"address" : "abc district"
"no.of slots" [
  {
"Mrng" : 10:30,
"Evening" : 11:20
}
]
}
]
```

then I need output like

```
response: {

"id" : 1,
"name" : "Hi",
"no.of slots" [
  {
"Mrng" : 10:30,
"Evening" : 11:20
},
{
"Mrng" : 12:00,
"Evening" : 4:00
}
],
"email" : "abc@gmail.com",
"address" : "abc district"

}
```

In no of slots If I have duplicates need to remove or if unique need to combine, any help will be appreciate.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class representing Mrng and Evening properties and override that class's equals and hash methods for comparing for these attributes. Then have a Set and generate instances and put elements to this.

Finally you will get a unique list and have a json string with some little research. This should be done to no.of.slots only

Comment: @NarayanaRaoKancharana is this what you expected answer?